# ¿Cómo puedo quitar los marcadores pode defecto de GoogleMaps en Flutter?

Tags: flutter, google-maps, dart

Me gustaría saber si existe alguna manera de **ocultar los marcadores por defecto en GoogleMaps** desde Flutter, deseo ocultar los marcadores por defecto y añadir en su lugar mi propio Set de marcadores personalizados.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lo encerrado en los círculos de color rojo es lo que se desea retirar. Muchas gracias.

Comment: Intenta verificar los documentos de openstreetmap maps, utilizando las direcciones específicas utilizando directivos universales

Answer (score 0):

Para solucionarlo **modifiqué el estilo del GoogleMap** durante la creación del mapa, haciendo uso de los estilos proporcionados por **snazzymaps.com**, en contreto utilicé este: https://snazzymaps.com/style/151/ultra-light-with-labels